# How do I only load js on the post-new.php and post.php pages in admin?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I have some script that is loading in the admin. I only need it to load on the new post and edit posts screens.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the page and enqueue your script accordingly:

```
global $pagenow;
if (! empty($pagenow) && ('post-new.php' === $pagenow || 'post.php' === $pagenow ))
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');

function enqueue_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(...);
} // function enqueue_my_scripts
```

Comment: I'd personally have put the conditional logic into the callback, aside from that i agree with the choice of hook. :)

Comment: @t31os Why make the parser travel further than necessary? ;) And also, you'd add an action that does not do anything for most of the pages/time.

Comment: Correct, but it looks prettier. The runtime difference should be pretty negligible to.

Comment: Chosen as the answer. Though the one above seems like it would work as well. I ended up figuring this out on my own but what you suggested is basically what I did.

Answer (score 8):

The global variable `$hook_suffix` is:

- `post-new.php` for the new post and
- `post.php` for the regular post editor

In `wp-admin/admin-header.php` there are some special hooks:

```
do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix);
do_action("admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_styles');
do_action("admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_scripts');
do_action("admin_head-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_head');
```

So you can use `admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix`, in your cases:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'your_prefix_enqueue_scripts' );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php',     'your_prefix_enqueue_scripts' );
```

To find the correct `$hook_suffix` for any admin page use something like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'print_hook_suffix' );

function print_hook_suffix()
{
    global $hook_suffix;

    print '$hook_suffix: ' . $hook_suffix;
}
```