# Slider's missing navigation

Tags: jquery, buddypress

I've got BuddyPress and Easy FancyBox installed, I've also got carouFredSel slider (not the WordPress plugin). When those two plugins are enabled, slider stops working properly (navigation bullets are missing).

Could it be some kind of jQuery conflict?

Here's header.php: http://pastebin.com/eBLpFBZ9 and here's page with the slider: http://adamklimowski.pl/chamois/

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Post the relevant code here please. Questions should not depend on third party services.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress loads jQuery in ["No Conflict" mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). The `$` alias does not work. This is the cause of most of the "jQuery doesn't work" questions on this site.

Your code is using that `$` alias, [despite the Codex warnings against doing so](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Use `jQuery.(document)` or [wrap your code like...](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

You should also not be embedding the script into the template like that. Save yourself some headaches and [register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) your scripts properly. By doing that you can easily load scripts only where needed and make use of very good dependency juggling.

## Related

[How Do I Use jQuery UI In My Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97533/how-do-i-use-jquery-ui-in-my-plugin/97534#97534)