# How to enqueue scripts in right way in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am developing a wordpress plugin and just came out with a problem with enqueue scripts.

I want to enqueue JQUERY UI (.js) and (.css) in my plugin.

- Is it better to enqueue it from Google CDN or from Wordpress bundled?
- If in a wordpress admin page there are 2 plugins active and both used JQUERY UI of different versions. Then will it be a conflict or problem?

I googled many pages and actually didn't still come with a perfect solution. Please share your experience and views regarding enqueue scripts in plugin.

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97533/how-do-i-use-jquery-ui-in-my-plugin

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to actually enqueue from the bundled version since it has a handle, this avoids conflicts.

If 2 scripts are enqueued using the same handle, `jquery-ui-core` for example (default WP one)  then only 1 script is loaded.

If 2 scripts are enqueued using different names then they will both be loaded.

This is especually true for scripts and CSS like jQuery-UI which include thier own hardcoded handles like `#tabs` which can cause problems with themes and other plugins.

In my opinion breaking a site is worse than having to load a few extra KB's.

Comment: Thanks..how will i load jquery ui css from wordpress bundled?
I mean i can load wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-core"). but what about itz CSS loading?

Comment: The only CSS included is for `jquery-ui-dialog` you will have to use your own, it's almost always better to create your own CSS with unique id and class names.