# Issues with wp_enqueue_script and jquery-ui

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, include, jquery-ui

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-shake');
```

..doesn't seem to work, no matter where I put it. I've tried the following and lots of googling:

```
function my_callback() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-shake');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_callback');
```

and

```
<?php
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-shake');
    get_header(); 
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How Do I Use jQuery UI In My Plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97533/how-do-i-use-jquery-ui-in-my-plugin)

Comment: What does "doesnt work" mean? Have you viewed source to see if the script loads? Or are you saying you can't make a script shake (which could be a whole boatload of other problem)

Comment: It isn't adding the script to <head>.

Comment: toscho: That is one of the docs that I read. I am doing the same thing and it's still not adding the script to <head>

Comment: Is the theme using the `wp_head` and `wp_footer` function calls? You said it's not loading in `<head>`, does that mean it's loading somewhere else or not at all?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are also including the jquery effects core... and jquery if it's not already being loaded.

```
function my_callback() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  // If not already loaded
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-shake');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_callback');
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be automatically included as Dependencies? Adding them made no difference for me.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the admin panel, or in a template file for the front-end of the site?

Comment: In a template on the front-end of the site.