# Use jQuery Datepicker code from plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, pages

Is it possible to access a plugins' functionality from a page template?

I would like to use

http://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-field-date-time-picker/

in a custom page with a form, so the user can choose date and time for a custom post type.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: ACF has a function and documentation for adding fields to the front end, see [Creating a front end form](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-a-front-end-form/).

Comment: See [How Do I Use jQuery UI In My Plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97533/how-do-i-use-jquery-ui-in-my-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Datepicker library does't really have anything to do with Wordpress. jQuery Datepicker can be used by itself and it can hook into any text box or form. See http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html and http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/